# 6L90 Transmission swap

Tags: transmission, gmc, compatibility

I'm swapping out a worn out 6L90 transmission that has over 220k on it in a 2011 GMC 2500 HD with one that has 89k on it from an identical truck. Will it have to be reflashed or reprogrammed to work?

Answer (score 1):

As long as it came out of another *like* vehicle, the Transmission Control Unit (TCU) **should not need reflashed**. What I mean by *like* is, another GMC or Chevrolet 2500 HD truck of the same year. As long as we are on par there, there shouldn't be any issues with the swap.